# Firestore setting id of existing document

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i'm looking for a way to change the document Id of a existing document. Is there a solution or do I need do copy all data and create a new document with the new document id?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, Apart from tags, you need to clearly articulate in your question on what framework you are using to store documents. What are the different options you already tried and what is failing. It would help people to review the question real quick and suggest answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to change the id of an existing Firestore document.

You will therefore need to "copy all data and create a new document with the new document id".